# What is fitted in a GARCH: residual or log-return?

Tags: residuals, fitting, garch

Given a time-series of log-return of SP500, then to obtain the volatility process what should we do? Some people say that we need using the ARMA model to withdraw the residual series, then plug this residual series into the GARCH model to obtain the conditional variance process? Or directly plug the log-return process of SP500 into the GARCH model to obtain the conditional variance?

I saw that in the book Introduction to Time Series in R, the author fits simulated residuals in GARCH model then he fits SP500 log returns in the GARCH model.

I got confused...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the log returns, you're essentially making the assumption that there is no conditional variation in the mean. In some circumstances you may want to explicitly model both, but other times it may be sufficient to assume a constant mean and focus on the conditional variance. Depends on what you're trying to do.

In addition, if you fit a GARCH model with raw log returns, then you're also implicitly assuming the mean is zero. Centering the data may be important if the mean is large (i.e. especially in lower frequency data).

Comment: I basically want to use an ARMA-GARCH model to model both my mean equation and variance equation. How should I proceed?Can you explain what you mean by no conditional variation in the mean?What would be the implication of that?

Comment: Can you explain mathematically what you meant? thanks

Comment: Basically if the mean varies over time, one way to model that is with ARMA. The residuals from a ARMA regression would (ideally) no longer have a time-varying mean. If it is important to do both, then you can take a pseudo-maximum likelihood approach, fit the ARMA model, get the residuals, then fit the Garch model to the residuals.

Comment: you mean if the series is not stationary in its mean?isn't there differencing for that?

Comment: If I fit the garch model to the log-returns, what would I get?the variance equation?is it possible to get the mean equation if I do that?                                                            If I first model the series using an ARMA,then model the residuals using a GARCH model, would'nt I need to re-estimate the parameters of the ARMA model?I saw in Statistics and Data Analysis for Financial Engineering talking about something like that but i'm not sure. thanks

Comment: I'm trying to discuss it generally. For stock indices, log returns are probably fine by themselves, but you have seemed to really emphasized the importance of ARMA, which could adjust a wide classes of processes for stationarity. You wouldn't need to re-estimate the ARMA model if you're doing pseudo-ML, but a Bayesian estimation or full ML would do both parts together. Why don't you just download a garch package for R or something and play around with it?

Comment: I tried a few garch packages here is what I found. I use SP500 data from the MASS package and tried fitting a garch model to it.Then I used forecast package to fit an arima model to the SP500 data, I then applied a garch model to the residual of the arima model. I get more or less the same coefficients in both cases. But my aim is to ultimately forecast return so I would need my equation for mean return. What do you mean the full ML do both parts together?you mean both the ARMA and GARCH model are estimated in parallel?Is that what is done in garchFit function from fGarch package?thanks

Comment: can I have an answer to that please?"What do you mean the full ML do both parts together?you mean both the ARMA and GARCH model are estimated in parallel?Is that what is done in garchFit function from fGarch package?" thanks

Comment: I mean that your maximum likelihood estimator is calculating all the coefficients to the model at once. Most people don't do it that way. They estimate the ARMA first, then the GARCH. It makes the calculations easier and is good enough.